# Severity of this tyre cut?

Tags: tires

[image]

I am a new driver and yesterday I drove part of the tyre on an elevated man hole cover and during parking saw this cut. It's a tubeless tyre and overnight I don't feel the tyre leaked any air. I am not sure how deep is the cut but should be less than 0.5 mm. Should I be worried about this cut and need to undertake any repair for this?

Comment: I guess you mean "less than 5 mm"?

Answer (score 5):

This is difficult to assess from the image - how deep is it is the main issue, but if it is holding air then it may not be too deep. Just from the image it is deeper than 0.5mm just by looking at its shape and the edges...

Have it checked by a tyre place you can trust or your favourite garage or mechanic.

If it was closer to the sidewall I would say change it, but this one may be ok.

Comment: Take it to a mechanic. I’d rather find out that the tire needs to be repaired/replaced while the car is stationary than while going down the highway at 75 mph.

Comment: @IconDaemon that’s what is said in my second paragraph...

Comment: I was injecting a little black humor into the discussion, @Solar Mike, bypassing the option to ignore the cut altogether. It is also possible that continuing to drive on the tire may widen the cut over time, as well as allowing debris to enter the cut and deepen it.

Answer (score 0):

As the gash is in the thicker, ridged portion of the tire there should be nothing but rubber there.

It should be fine.